# Constexpr class template member function with deduced void return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, c++14, return-type-deduction

Consider the following simple class `X` and class template `Y<T>` that each define four `constexpr` members, three of which have their return types deduced (new C++1y feature), and another subset of three that makes use of another new C++1y feature: the relaxed `constexpr` function that now also can have side-effects and a `void` return type.

Below a small experiment with the interaction of these features:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct X
{
    constexpr void fun() {}             // OK
    constexpr auto gun() {}             // OK
              auto hun() {}             // OK
    constexpr auto iun() { return 0; }  // OK
};

template<class T>
struct Y
{
    constexpr void fun() {}             // OK
  //constexpr auto gun() {}             // ERROR, why?
              auto hun() {}             // OK
    constexpr auto iun() { return 0; }  // OK
};

int main() 
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<X>().fun())>::value, "");    
    static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<X>().gun())>::value, "");    
    static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<X>().hun())>::value, "");    
    static_assert(std::is_same<int , decltype(std::declval<X>().iun())>::value, "");    

    static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<Y<X>>().fun())>::value, "");    
  //static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<Y<X>>().gun())>::value, "");    
    static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<Y<X>>().hun())>::value, "");    
    static_assert(std::is_same<int , decltype(std::declval<Y<X>>().iun())>::value, "");    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42ae3499ebff2c44) that only compiles on Clang >= 3.4 (because it is the only compiler that supports both the auto return type deduction and the relaxed `constexpr` functions)

The `gun()` function inside the class template `Y<T>` (but **not** inside the class `X`) generates a compiler error:

> no return statement in constexpr function

**Question**: is the combination a `constexpr` function with an automatically deduced `void` return type inside a class template not possible as per the Standard, or is it a compiler bug in Clang?

Comment: Can a `constexpr` reasonably refer to a `void` type?? I remember having cases where I needed to allow `void` as template parameter, but specializations used `void*` internally (not C++11 though) ...

Comment: As a workaround, try `constexpr auto gun() {return;}`. Or trailing `-> void`, but that's redundant.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in C++1y, `constexpr` functions can have side effects (e.g. incrementing an index) as long as the overall effect of a function is seen at compile-time. Wrapping such an increment inside a small `void` function would give the above error.

Comment: @remyabel yes that works, tnx. I'm still puzzeled why this only happens inside class templates, not inside classes.

Comment: [decl.spec.auto]/10 "If a function with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type has no return statements, the return
type is deduced as though from a return statement with no operand at the closing brace of the function
body." That is, `auto` allows this. And I can't see where `constexpr` would explicitly require a return-statement.

Comment: @dyp yes, which explains the `X::gun()` part. The `Y<T>::gun()` part is puzzling.

Comment: @TemplateRex Doesn't seem to matter if its in a class. A normal template function will proc the same error, i.e. `template<typename T> constexpr auto swap() {}` Note that gcc does not choke on this line of code. It only chokes on the ones inside the class, template or not.

Comment: @TemplateRex Saw you mentioning the side effect in your question after posting the comment ...

Comment: @TemplateRex Ignore the last one. I meant to say gcc chokes on `struct x` but not `struct y`.

Comment: @remyabel gcc does not support void constexpr, it already chokes on `X::fun()`.

Comment: Here's a guess: If the constexpr function has side effects, then those must be known to the compiler, which means that the information has to be transmitted across translation units. With a class, i.e. a static class member, this is easy on account of the single definition of the member. But with templates, linking requires deduplication, and you would have to be able to preserve the constexpr state update across this deduplication.

Comment: This is a clang bug; I've filed it as [PR18746](http://llvm.org/PR18746). The problem is that Clang defers deducing the return type of `gun` until `Y` is instantiated, but then (mistakenly) thinks that it has non-`void` return type when checking whether it's a valid `constexpr` function (because the return type is `auto`, which is not `void`...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround for a normal template function, you can do:

```
template<typename T> constexpr auto gun();
template<>
constexpr auto gun<void>() {}
```

Following the same logic, I think the following should not change your original code too much:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct X
{
    constexpr auto gun() {}             
};

template<class T>
struct Y
{
    constexpr auto gun();
};

template<>
constexpr auto Y<X>::gun() { }

int main() 
{ 
    static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<Y<X>>().gun())>::value, "");    
}
```

Also as already stated, an empty `return` statement will do the trick.

```
constexpr auto gun() {return;}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort, but I think I'd rather keep the explicit return type than to use a specialization. The explicit `return` inside is also acceptable, so if you could please change that.

Comment: @TemplateRex Made a small mistake, forgot to add constexpr for the first example. Honestly I can't figure it out. It only seems to complain if you attempt to define it without specializing it.

Comment: that sounds like it's some weird interaction with template instantiation